# flutter firebase: Allowing User to specify time for receiving notification. firebase functions

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Flutter app that users will go to every single day.

Users want to be able to choose a specific time in the day to receive the notification, and each user will have a different time.

Is there a way to use Firebase functions to efficiently do this? If firebase functions doesn't allow this, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with a single device, you don't need Firebase for this at all. Just schedule a local task/alarm and display a local notification when the time comes.

If you want to allow scheduling the notification on one device and displaying it on another device, I recommend sending a message to the other device (through FCM or any other data sync of your choice) right away when the user enters the data. Then once again on the other device(s), you can schedule a task/alarm and then handle it as a local notification.

If you really want to schedule the delivery of the message to a specific time, have a look at the documentation on [enqueueing functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions), which allows you to dynamically schedule the execution of a function.

Comment: Can you add example with flutter for a single device local task?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. That said, I searched for [flutter run code at a specific time](https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+run+code+at+a+specific+time) earlier already and that showed some promising results.